# Magento 2 account temporarily disabled. Have tried unlocking

Tags: magento-2.1

I have recently copied a site from a client server and set it up on an AWS EC2 instance. The front end of the site works fine, however when trying to log into the backend, I receive the error "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled".

I have already tried unlocking the account as suggested in another similar thread here, and when I tried creating a new user through the CLI, I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try to unlock your user directly via the database. there's a "admin_user" table with "failures_num", "first_failure" and "lock expires". You can try to set them to "0","NULL","NULL".I have not tested this, but probably worth a try. And ofcourse make a backup first. Can you run any other CLI which tries to change the database, or do you always get the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the login issue was resolved partly by disabling Page caching within Magento - `system > cache management`. If you need to confirm that you are entering the correct password (sounds silly, but caching was a nightmare for me here!), you can do this via `vendor/zendframework/zend-crypt/src/Utils.php` and modify to output the hashes at the login screen:

```
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    echo "Expected:" . $expected;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Actual:"  . $actual;
    return hash_equals($expected, $actual);
}
```

The `SQLSTATE...` error was simply caused by a lack of resources on the server. I just upgraded the AWS instance and the site is working as it should.

If things still aren't working for you as they should, ensure that you clear `var/cache`, `var/generation`.

Hopefully someone finds this useful!